# Existence of magic labelings on graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Given some undirected simple graph $G$, a magic labeling is an edge labeling such that each edge is assigned some positive integer such that the sum of the labels of the edges adjacent to each vertex is equivalent for every vertex.

I've seen some definitions of magic labelings require the integers on the edge labels to be distinct. Omitting that constraint, is it possible to verify the existence of such magic labelings on graphs? For example, we can easily guarantee the existence of a magic labeling on any complete graph by labeling each edge with the same integer. If verifiable, is there some way to find such a labeling for more general/other classes of graphs?

Comment: Do you mean *prove* the existence? *Verify* is often used in a different sense, as in “I claim not only that there exist such beasts, but that $B$ is just such a beast. Verify that $B$ does indeed have this property.” In general, verification problems can be easier to solve than their more general existence-proof cousins.

Comment: Yes - apologies, I do indeed mean proving the existence as opposed to verifying.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G(A, B)$ be a graph.

We say that $G$ is perfect matching covered if each edge belongs to a perfect matching.

We say that $c:E\to [0, 1]$ is a perfect fractional matching if $\sum_{e\in\delta(v)}c(e) = 1$ for every $v\in V$.

We will say that $G$ is perfect fractional matching covered if for every edge $e\in E$, there exists a perfect fractional matching such that $c(e) > 0$.

By summing matchings, we mean summing the edge weights $c$ that is $1$ if an edge is matched, and $0$ if an edge is unmatched.

We note $B(G)(V_A, V_B, E_{B(G)})$ the bipartite double graph of $G$, where $V_A = \{a_v| v\in V\}$, $V_B = \{b_v| v\in V\}$, $E_{B(G)} = \{a_ub_v, a_vb_u | uv\in E\}$. For a given labeling $c$ of the edges of $B(G)$, we call $\tilde{c}$ its symetric labeling, defined by $\tilde{c}(a_ub_v) = c(a_vb_u)$ for all $a_ub_v\in B(G)$.

We recall a classical result:

---

**Lemma:** graphs $G$ having a perfect fractional matching are exactly the graphs for which $B(G)$ has a perfect matching.

*Proof:*
If $G$ has a perfect fractional matching, then we easily find a perfect fractional matching for $B(G)$. Because $B(G)$ is bipartite, it must have a perfect matching.

If $B(G)$ has a perfect matching, we can find a perfect fractional matching by averaging this perfect matching with its symmetric counterpart.

---

We recall a classical result from Berge:

---

**Lemma:** Let $G(V_A, V_B, E)$ be a bipartite graph, and suppose we have a perfect matching. Orient the matched edges from $V_A$ to $V_B$, and the unmatched edges from $V_B$ to $V_A$. $G$ is perfect matching covered iff and only if the oriented graph is strongly connected.

---

We will show this:

**Theorem:** $G$ has a magic labeling if and only if $G$ is fractional perfect matching covered.

**First direction** Suppose $G$ has a magic labeling summing to $c$ at each vertex. Then by normalizing by $c$ the weights on edges, we obtain a perfect fractional matching that is positive everywhere, so $G$ is perfect fractional matching covered.

**Second direction:** Suppose $G$ is perfect fractional matching covered.

We can show a slightly stronger statement. A perfect fractional matching in $B(G)$ is in the convex hull of the perfect matchings of $B(G)$, so if $c(e)>0$, we can find a perfect matching where $e$ is matched. Using the line of reasoning, we can then show that $G$ is perfect fractional matching covered iff $B(G)$ is perfect matching covered.

By summing perfect matchings that covers $B(G)$, we obtain a magical labeling of $B(G)$ (and by normalizing it, a fractional perfect matching that is positive everywhere).

By summing the magic labeling of $B(G)$ with its symetric labeling, we obtain a magic labeling for $G$ (and by normalizing it, a fractional perfect matching that is positive everywhere).

---

**Algorithm:**
Combining all of this we get the following algorithm that decides if a graph $G$ admits a magic labeling:

- Construct $B(G)$
- Search for a perfect matching in $B(G)$. If there is none, $G$ does not admit a magic labeling.
- Orient matched edges from $V_A$ to $V_B$ and unmatched edge from $V_B$ to $V_A$. Check if the graph is strongly connected (Tarjan algorithm). If it is not, $G$ does not admit a magic labeling.

  - REPEAT until all edges are crossed
  - Cross all the matched edges that are not already crossed
  - Find an unmatched edges
  - Find a cycle containing this (there must be one since the graph is strongly connected)
  - Switch the matched edges of the cycle to unmatched, and the unatched edges to matched. You get a new matching.
- sum all the matchings found to get a magic labeling

Comment: Can you double-check your definition of *perfect fractional matching*? I feel like it is off. Also, some important words are missing in the statement of the first lemma

Comment: Thanks, I edited